# Converting datepicker to string

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

How do you convert a DatePicker value to a String?

Currently I have a TextView setup, which the DatePicker passes its value to. Its displayed fine. Using that String to pass to a SQLite database isn't working however and returns

```
android.widget.TextView@41258880
```

When the databases fields are pulled up. I am currently taking the value and passing it to a string within the following TRY/Catch statement:

```
case R.id.btnUpdateDB:
            boolean worked = true;
            try {
                String dbWeight = curWeight.getText().toString();
                String dbWaist = curWaist.getText().toString();
                String dbChest = curChest.getText().toString();
                String dbLegs = curLegs.getText().toString();
                String dbArms = curArms.getText().toString();
                String dbDate = displayDate.toString();
                Stats entry = new Stats(MainActivity.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(dbWeight, dbWaist, dbChest, dbLegs, dbArms, dbDate);
                entry.close();
                break;
```

I feel that the following line is incorrect:

```
String dbDate = displayDate.toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called the method `toString` directly on the widget. According to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.toString%28%29) it prints :

```
public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

That's why you get :

```
android.widget.TextView@41258880
```

You have to do instead :

`String dbDate = displayDate.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

if displayDate is TextView You get its value just like You do with other fields before

```
String dbDate = displayDate.getText().toString();
```

Comment: If it wasn't working but You had an idea how to fix it don't assume  idea may be wrong but test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String dateFormat = dateformat.format(new Date(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth()));
```